# Python Deep Learning: Shape of irregular multidimensional data sets

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I am using TFLearn and python 3.7 to create a my first neural network, which goal is to play snake. 
The game consists of a 10x10 board, with empty spaces shown as a 0, the goal the snake is trying to eat shown as -1, the head of the snake shown as a 1, and each consecutive part of the snake shown as the previous part of the snake + 1. For example, a game state could be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

-1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The state is stored as a single array, of size 100.

I have created the game and the training data, which is a list of lists containing a state and the action taken (0 - 3 inclusive, representing the 4 directions). An element of the input data could be:

```
[[0, 0, ... 0], 2]
```

In the above element of input data, the state was [0, 0, ... 0] and the action taken was 2 (move down).

I am having difficulty determining the shape of this data, as the action is an int not a list of size 100.  I assume the shape of the data would be:

```
[None, numberOfInputElements, 2, 100],
```

though this seems odd as the action taken is an integer and not a list of size 100 as is defined in the data shape.

Would this be correct, and if not, what would the correct shape be (if possible, please provide an explanation as to why).

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have one tensor representing the input image with the shape `[None, 100]` (or better, `[None, 10, 10]` so you can try a convolutional approach) and another tensor representing the action with the shape `[None]`, or perhaps `[None,4]`, where the action is represented in one-hot fashion (this is useful for defining cost functions such as the cross-entropy).

An unrelated idea - assuming the game arena is cyclic, always center the matrix around the snake's head (so the snake's head is always at the same location).